# Is there any fixed rule as to when we should use the structure "the + noun + of + name" instead of "name + noun"?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, sentence-patterns

Is it "the jungle of Amazon" or "the Amazon jungle"? "the university of Oxford" or "the Oxford university"?

Sometimes both structures seem fine (to me) (e.g. I've heard both "the tower of London" and, maybe less formally, "the London tower"), but sometimes only one pattern seems to be correct (e.g. in "Parallax restaurant". I assume we cannot say "the restaurant of Parallax").

Also, I've come across a different pattern with certain nouns in which the word "of" is removed altogether (e.g. in "Lake Michigan". It doesn't sound correct to say "the lake of Michigan", but I assume we *can* say "Michigan lake", right?)

Is there any solid rule on when to use which?

P.S. as a non native speaker of English I may have made some speculations. Please do tell me if I was wrong.

Comment: Most such names have an official correct form, either by choice or tradition. Many universities, including Oxford, are officially 'the University of X', though 'Oxford University' might be used in informal speech, and some, such as Keele University, have their official name in that form. It's usually 'Lake X' and 'River X', though some geographical names are in the reverse order. I've _never_ heard 'London Tower', as it wouldn't be clear which tower was being referred to.